# comboBox select for first value

Tags: c#, combobox

I have simple comboBox with:

```
cb_listaUczniow.ValueMember = "Key";
cb_listaUczniow.DisplayMember = "Value";
```

And I have constructor for this Form (classID is not important yet):

```
MyForm(int classID, string selectedName)
{
   cb_listaUczniow.ValueMember = "Key";
   cb_listaUczniow.DisplayMember = "Value";
   comboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(makeList(classID), null);
}
```

makeList return Dictionary

and How i can select in comboBox item with "Value" (displayMember) where names selectedName?

for example (pseudo-Code):

```
MyForm(3, "Gall Anonim") -> comboBox.Item.Selected = comboBox.Item.where("Value" == "Gall Anonim");
```

**How i can set it?**

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you can simply set `ComboBox`'s `SelectedValue` property to the corresponding value :

```
comboBox.SelectedValue = 3;
```

That will make "Gall Anonim" the selected item of the `ComboBox`.